# NOTEPAD++ Checking if on a line there is twice a specific charater

Tags: regex, notepad++

So it's been 2H of search for nothing, i looked into like 30 stackoverflow links but still not getting the expression i want.

So basically there is something like this in the file **`:?????rzzzu`** and i want to check if on a line there is twice the ":" character so if the line is **`:????rifo:`** then it would find it.

I tried with **`^(?:[^:]*:[^:]*){0,2}$`** but this go on 2 lines and can't fix it can someone help me please ?

Comment: Using a negated character class `[^:]` will match any char except a colon but it will match a newline. You can exclude matching that as well and the quantifier should be `{2}` for exactly 2 matches `^(?:[^:\r\n]*:[^:\r\n]*){2}$` https://regex101.com/r/qNStNe/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

`.*?:.*?:.*`

Make sure that the checkbox "`.` matches newline" is not checked.

The `.*?` will match any character that is not a newline until it can match the next character in the regular expression (i.e. `:`)

`:` will literally match the first `:` on the line

The same happens a second time, and then `.*` will match the remainder of the line. It will stop matching at the end of the line, since `.` does not match a newline character (unless you check that checkbox).

So, all this means you don't actually need to use `^` or `$`, although you could if you think it is clearer.